# How do I use yum to download software only from Centos 5.4 and not the latest

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

Requirement is to download software from Centos 5.4. When I do yum install , I get the latest version and not the one available for Centos 5.4.

How do I configure yum to download only from 5.4 repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my answer to your other question you need to find a repository that has a maintained, static entry for 5.4.

Most repositories have just one repository for each major version and upgrade it as new minor versions are released. But some keep specific repositories for each version independently (at least for a little while).

I would start with checking whether your current repository has an explicitly 5.4 repository (by using the URL in the `yum.conf` or `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` file for the repository).

If that doesn't work out you get to try other mirrors as listed on the CentOS mirrors website.

As a fallback, and I encourage you to try to find a valid mirror first, you can find this sort of minor version specific repository on http://vault.centos.org.